# How to make Disqus notify my backend when a comment happens?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, disqus

The route I'm taking right now is by utilizing the `onNewComment` event from the client Disqus library.

When that event happens, my frontend is notifying my backend though POST message that a comment happened, and so consequently the backend takes appropriate actions like push notifications and such.

However, this approach is obviously hacky. It's not client's job to notify the backend that the state in Disqus have changed. It's Disqus' job to do this. But I wasn't able to find this in the docs. Pointers?